# How to fetch string with double quotes from Database in Java

Tags: java, string, jdbc

I need to fetch following JSON string from database in java

```
SETTING_VALUE - [{"123","234","235"}]
```

I used result set to fetch it -

```
String value=rs.getString("SETTING_VALUE")
```

But java throwing exception -

```
"Cannot convert value into String"
```

How can I fetch these value into String using JDBC.

Comment: are you sure you are getting exception at same line ? could you share exact exception ?

Comment: What is the column type of `SETTING_VALUE`?  Which database are you using?

Comment: And, as always, what is the exact and complete stack trace of the exception?

Comment: Sorry, Datatype of column is not String . It is CLOB and I'm using Oracle DB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the data type of column SETTING_VALUE?
It's working in MYSQL. The column named json has data type VARCHAR.

```
    String URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/test";
    String username="root";
    String pwd = "";
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(URL,username,pwd);
    Statement stat = con.createStatement();
    stat.execute("SELECT * FROM getjson");

    ResultSet resultSet = stat.getResultSet();

    while(resultSet.next()){
        String data = resultSet.getString("json");
        System.out.println("JSON DATA IS " + data);
    }
```

The output is:

[image]

Comment: Datatype of My column is CLOB. So, I'm unable to convert it to String